# Changing symlink path creates additional folder

Tags: filesystems, symlink, path

I tried to change an existing symlink which is accessable under `cd ~/symlink_file_name` to another folder with the following command:

```
ln -sfn /usr/home/myusername/testfolder symlink_file_name
```

(since the testfolder is also accessable via `cd ~/testfolder` and shows me with `pwd` the context: `/usr/home/myusername/testfolder`).

Running `pwd` gives me `/usr/home/myusername/testfolder`.

It works (and I get no additional response or error from `ln` command), but unfortunately it adds a folder `myusername` to the `testfolder` so that the symlink then points to:

```
/usr/home/myusername/testfolder/myusername
```

instead to:

```
/usr/home/myusername/testfolder
```

which i originally set it to (as you can tell from the `ln` command at the beginning of my post).

How can I prevent this that it creates the additional folder?

Comment: Please provide a worked example in your question. Start with `pwd` (and its output) so we have some context. Then the `ln...` command (and any message it may give you - although I wouldn't particularly expect one). Then explain what's not right, what you expected, and how you tried to fix it.

Comment: @roaima I updated my post a little bit. Sorry but I'm pretty new to linux. Why should I paste the `pwd` output, and for which path?

Comment: `pwd` will give us the directory context in which you're running the `ln -s`. By all means obfuscate BOTH commands similarly if you would like to hide the precise name of one or more of directories. But without the context we can't see where you've put `symlink_file_name` and so we can't reliably determine why you should get the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: try to run the command `pwd`. inside this path /usr/home/myusername/testfolder  what is the results?

Comment: @roaima @Kasper I've updated my original post. I have the folder I want to point to in the (i guess its called) root path (which I access via `cd ~/testfolder`). With `pwd` command I get the context: `/usr/home/myusername/testfolder` and I want to point to that which works with the command I used but it creates a folder then and points to this folder like so: `/usr/home/myusername/testfolder/myusername`

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this at all.

Comment: @roaima can it possible be that my hoster makes this? Because when I try to delete the old symlink with `rm symlink_file_name` it deletes the file (i think because i don't get any error message) but then the symlink file is still there?

Comment: Ah. Does `pwd` and `/bin/pwd` give the same result? I bet they are different (although in _most_ circumstances they would usually be the same). In which case `/bin/pwd` will give you the true path to your current directory.

Comment: @roaima `/bin/pwd` also shows the same path as if i do it under `cd ~`. So the path in both cases is `/usr/home/myusername`

Comment: That's a pity. Having a symbolic link in one's HOME directory path, which is also masked by the shell, is one area that can really add confusion to symlink creation.